# DirectX scene with cad style

Tags: directx

How can I create a 3D scene whith directx that looks like freecad? I tried to work on the shader but with bad results.

if anyone can help me I am very grateful

I have a render like this

[image]

but I want a render like this:

[image]

Comment: For me it looks like rendering via phong lighting with high ambient. Moreover all edges are outlined as used in toon shaders. Maybe you should look into them or read about sobel edge filter. For more you have to provide a more detailed question.

Comment: thanks [gnietschow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1339365/gnietschow), you have other ideas to obtain a rendering like the image below?

Comment: I suggest to start with the black border. Search the internet for something like "edge detection shader" and try to apply it to your scene, afterwards it will look very similar. Perhaps you need another lighting curve as linear black to white, which could be designed with a texture. Try to set up your light as in the freecad scene and look at the differences, are the shadowed parts lighter => add ambient, etc..

Comment: Yes, ["toon shading"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading) or "cel shading" are good search terms also.